# how can i access variable outside a upload function from cloudinary

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

How can I access `response.url` outside the upload function?

```
var cloudinaryUrl = null;
    if (req.files['imagefile']) {
        var imgUrl = req.files['imagefile'][0].path;
        cloudinary.uploader.upload(imgUrl, function (error, response) {
            cloudinaryUrl = response.url;
            console.log("cloudinaryURL>>", cloudinaryUrl); 
        });
        console.log("outside", cloudinaryUrl);
    }
```

The output outside the `upload` function gives null.

Comment: You don't.  You use that variable INSIDE the callback where it's made available or, if you really want, you can call a function from within that callback and pass the URL to it and use it inside that function.  This is asynchronous code development in Javascript.  The ONLY place you can use that result is inside that callback or in a function you call from there.

Comment: @jfriend00 this comment of yours helped me to understand the concept of synchronous and asynchronous at that time. I know it's a bit late to thank you, but it's never too late. Thank you very much.